# BASH output format

Tags: bash

I would like to format the output from the log file to a single line using BASH:

Log output:

```
# egrep "^(Infected|Cleaned)" /var/log/scan.log
Infected:          files - 0, objects 0
Cleaned:           files - 0, objects 0
```

I was able to print the results on one line but I'm not sure how I can format it and remove spaces:

```
# egrep "^(Infected|Cleaned)" /var/log/scan.log | awk '/Infected/{if (x) print x; x="" } { x = (!x) ? $0 : x "; " $0 } END { print x }'
Infected:          files - 0, objects 0; Cleaned:           files - 0, objects 0
```

Desired format:

```
Infected:F-0, O-0; Cleaned:F-0, O-0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean

```
awk '/Infected|Cleaned/{ORS=";"; print $1 "F-"$4 "O-"$6}' inputfile
```

will produce output

```
Infected:F-0,O-0;Cleaned:F-0,O-0;
```

`ORS` output record seperator is set to `;` which seperates the differnt line.

`/Infected|Cleaned/` select the lines that match the pattern

EDIT

To add a trailling newline

```
awk '/Infected|Cleaned/{ORS=";"; print $1 "F-"$4 "O-"$6}END{print "\n"}'
```

OR

```
awk '/Infected|Cleaned/{ORS=";"; print $1 "F-"$4 "O-"$6}' sam; echo
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add a trailing new line?

Comment: @HTF you are welcome :) to add trailing new line just add a `print "\n"` in `END` block. Will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

horribly quick and dirty:

```
egrep "^(Infected|Cleaned)" /var/log/scan.log | awk '/Infected/{if (x) print x; x="" } { x = (!x) ? $0 : x "; " $0 } END { print x }' | sed 's/\s//g' | sed 's/files/F/g' | sed 's/objects/ O-/g' | sed 's/;/; /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've piped the output to perl one-liner, this should do it

```
| perl -ne 's/\s+files\s+\-\s+/ F-/g; s/\s+objects\s+/ O-/g; print'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = " +"; ORS = " " }; { print $1, "F-", $4, "O-", $6 }' /var/log/scan.log
```

FS: field separator, set to one or more spaces

ORS: record separator for output, set to a space

With this value of FS, the desired fields are 1, 4, 6; the trailing separators (":", ",", ";", resp.) will be included.